# Check If Statement when you are dynamically creating something?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am dynamically creating rows in my table using JavaScript. I need to add `If` statement inside a `<td>` which I am creating dynamically. Inside my `<td>` I have an anchor tag `<a>`. I need to add anchor tag only if it satisfies my `If` statement. Following is my code:

```
var IsAdmin = true;
var row;
row = "<tr><td>" + if(IsAdmin == true){ + "<a href='#'> </a>" + } + "</td></tr>"
```

I am getting following error in my console:

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token if

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a ternary statement which returns the string you want if `IsAdmin` is true, an empty string otherwise, like this:

```
var IsAdmin = true;
var row;
row = "<tr><td>" + (IsAdmin ? "<a href='#'> </a>" : "") + "</td></tr>"
```

Comment: What if I have to use OR operator. e.g. `If(IsAdmin || HavePermission ? "" :"")`

Comment: In that case `row = "<tr><td>" + (IsAdmin || HavePermission ? "<a href='#'> </a>" : "") + "</td></tr>"`

Comment: It should, but maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean with your previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `if` that way. Do

```
var IsAdmin = true;
var row = "<tr><td>"; 
if(IsAdmin == true) {
    row += "<a href='#'> </a>";
}
row += "</td></tr>";
```

Or you can use the ternary statement as mentioned.